# Switch to admin theme based on path using hook_init() or template.php in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I'm running a site that uses a separate admin theme. I'd like to include a couple additional pages that use the admin stylesheets. How can I apply the theme selectively to these pages. I'd rather do this in hook_init() or template.php. I don't want to add any more contrib modules to the site at this point. Thanks for any illumination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Administration theme](http://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) module will do it, but given you'd like to do it yourself, it does cast some light on that path by suggesting the [`hook_admin_theme_check()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/admin_theme/admin_theme.api.php/function/hook_admin_theme_check/7) and [`hook_admin_theme_info()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/admin_theme/admin_theme.api.php/function/hook_admin_theme_info/7) hooks.

Comment: I did enable the Administration theme module which worked nicely - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [Administration theme](https://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) for that but if you just want to use the admin theme for a single path you can define it in hook_init

```
/*
 * Implements hook_init().
 * Use the admin theme on path 'batch'
 */
function MODULENAME_init() {
  if (arg(0) == 'batch') {
    global $custom_theme;
    $admin_theme = variable_get('admin_theme', 'garland');
    init_theme();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to enable more modules (like the admin_theme module), and prefer to write a few lines of code to achive the same thing, you can use [hook_custom_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7).

e.g. This snippet switches the user to the admin theme when they're viewing the revision comparison report from the diff module.

```
function MODULENAME_custom_theme() {
  global $conf;
  $args = arg();

  // Set the admin theme when viewing a diff comparison with the diff module.
  if (isset($args[3]) && $args[3] == "diff") {
    return array($conf['admin_theme']);
  }
}
```